# R: "Error in dimnames(x)[[2]] <- levels : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array" when trying to produce likert skale graphics

Tags: r, likert

I have a probably very basic question about data.frame structures in R. I have the following data from `a *.dta` file put into a data.frame with `read.dta (library(foreign))`.

```
dput(head(barriers))
structure(list(risk = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("Important", 
"Somewhat important", "Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant"), class = "factor"), 
cap = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("Important", 
"Somewhat important", "Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant"
), class = "factor"), FS_qual = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, NA), .Label = c("Important", "Somewhat important", "Somewhat unimportant", 
"Unimportant"), class = "factor"), best_prac = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Important", "Somewhat important", 
"Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant"), class = "factor"), 
const_risk = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("Important", 
"Somewhat important", "Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant"
), class = "factor"), appr = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, NA), .Label = c("Important", "Somewhat important", "Somewhat unimportant", 
"Unimportant"), class = "factor"), instr = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, NA), .Label = c("Important", "Somewhat important", 
"Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant"), class = "factor"), 
refin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("Important", 
"Somewhat important", "Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant"
), class = "factor"), reg = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
NA), .Label = c("Important", "Somewhat important", "Somewhat unimportant", 
"Unimportant"), class = "factor"), prop_qual = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA), .Label = c("Important", "Somewhat important", 
"Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant"), class = "factor")), datalabel = "", time.stamp = "13 Apr 2015 19:26", formats = c("%8.0g", 
"%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%30.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%106s", "%10.0g", 
"%45s", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", 
"%36s", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%10.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", 
"%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%87s", "%14.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", 
"%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%10.0g", "%8.0g", 
"%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%10.0g", 
"%10.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%10.0g", 
"%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", 
"%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%20.0g", "%82s", "%17.0g", "%17.0g", 
"%17.0g", "%17.0g", "%17.0g", "%17.0g", "%17.0g", "%17.0g", "%70s", 
"%21.0g"), types = c(253L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 255L, 255L, 106L, 
255L, 45L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 36L, 251L, 251L, 
255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 87L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 
251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 255L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 
251L, 251L, 255L, 255L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 251L, 255L, 255L, 
255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 82L, 
255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 70L, 251L), val.labels =            c("", 
"", "", "ownership", "Q36", "q37", "", "q38", "", "q39", "q39", 
"q39", "q39", "q39", "q39", "", "q39", "q39", "", "q310", "q310", 
"q310", "q310", "q310", "q310", "", "q411", "", "", "q413", "q413", 
"q413", "q413", "q413", "", "q413", "q413", "q413", "q413", "q413", 
"q413", "q413", "q414", "", "q413", "q413", "q413", "q413", "q413", 
"", "q310", "q310", "q310", "q310", "q310", "q310", "q310", "q310", 
"q310", "q310", "q310", "", "q417", "q417", "q417", "q417", "q417", 
"q417", "q417", "q417", "", "type"), var.labels = c("Bank ID", 
"BUKU: Type of Bank’s Activity based on Capital", "Bank ID", 
"Ownership", "Q36_Do you consider sustainable finance as a profitable     business area? ", 
"Q37_Does your institution’s 2015 business plan contain financing for     sustainable", 
"Q37_Year planned", "Q38_Does your company have special unit that handles sustainable finance?", 
"Q38_Sustainable Finance Unit", "Q39_A Dummy: Ever financed any sector?", 
"Q39_A Have you ever provided financing to support eco-tourism", 
"Q39_A Have you ever provided financing to support energy efficiency", 
"Q39_A Have you ever provided financing to support power production (•       Powe", 
"Q39_A Have you ever provided financing to support organic agriculture?", 
"Q39_A Have you ever provided financing to support waste treatment?", 
"Q39_Name of other supported sustainable sectors", "Q39_A Have you ever     provided financing to support recycled crafts/products?", 
"Q39_A Have you ever provided financing to support waste treatment?", 
"Q39_Total financing volume to support sustainable projects in 2014", 
"Q310a Barrier for your institution to extend loan on sustainable finance: too ri", 
"Q310b Barrier for your institution to extend loan on sustainable finance: Not pr", 
"Q310c Barrier for your institution to extend loan on sustainable finance: Too co", 
"Q310d Barrier for your institution to extend loan on sustainable finance: Lack o", 
"Q310e Barrier for your institution to extend loan on sustainable finance: Instit", 
"Q310f Barrier for your institution to extend loan on sustainable finance: others", 
"Q310f Other barrier name", "Q411 In the past 5 years, has your institution received a request for financing ", 
"Q412 In the past 5 years, has your institution financed an RE project as part of", 
"Q413a Number of RE projects financed", "Q413b Dummy: Has financed biomass projects?", 
"Q413b Dummy: Has financed geothermal projects?", "Q413b Dummy: Has financed hydro projects?", 
"Q413b Dummy: Has financed solar projects?", "Q413b Dummy: Has financed wind projects?", 
"Q413c Total RE financing", "Q413d Dummy: Has financed using Equity Finance?", 
"Q413d Dummy: Has financed using Debt Finance (long term: more than 4 years)?", 
"Q413d Dummy: Has financed using Debt Finance (medium term: 1 to 4 years)?", 
"Q413d Dummy: Has financed using Mezzanine Finance ?", "Q413d Dummy: Has financed using Other", 
"Q413d Dummy: Has financed using Project Finance", "Q413d Dummy: Has financed using Debt Finance (short term: less than 1 year)?", 
"Q414 In the past 5 years, has your institution financed an RE project as part of", 
"Q415a Number of RE CSR projects", "Q413b Dummy: Has financed biomass projects with CSR?", 
"Q413b Dummy: Has financed geothermal projects with CSR?", "Q413b Dummy: Has financed hydro projects with CSR?", 
"Q413b Dummy: Has financed solar projects with CSR?", "Q413b Dummy: Has financed wind projects with CSR?", 
"Q415c Total CSR RE Investment", "Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  High default risk", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Lack of in-house capacities", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Low quality of feasibility studies", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Lack of best-practice RE financing examples", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  High risk of construction delays ", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  High costs of project appraisal", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Lack of adequate financial instruments ", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Lack of long-term refinancing opportunities", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Restrictive banking regulation ", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Low quality of project proposals", 
"Q416 Barrier for RE Investment:  Others", "Q416 Barrier for RE Investment: Name of other barrier", 
"Q417 Support Initiatives: In-house training and manuals", "Q417 Support    Initiatives: Access to external technical expertise", 
"Q417 Support Initiatives: Guarantee instruments", "Q417 Support Initiatives: Long-term refinancing sources", 
"Q417 Support Initiatives: Public co-financing opportunities", 
"Q417 Support Initiatives: Portfolio requirements by OJK", "Q417 Support Initiatives: Disclosure requirements by OJK", 
"Q417 Support Initiatives: Others", "Q417 Support Initiatives: Name of other initiatives", 
"Type of Financial Institution"), version = 12L, label.table = structure(list(
Q36 = structure(1:3, .Names = c("Yes", "No", "Don't know"
)), q37 = structure(1:3, .Names = c("Yes", "No", "Not Yet"
)), q38 = structure(1:2, .Names = c("Yes", "No")), q39 = structure(0:1,    .Names = c("No", 
"Yes")), q310 = structure(1:4, .Names = c("Important", "Somewhat important", 
"Somewhat unimportant", "Unimportant")), q411 = structure(1:4, .Names = c("Yes", 
"Not yet", "Don't know", "Not applicable")), q413 = structure(0:1, .Names = c("No", 
"Yes")), q414 = structure(1:3, .Names = c("Yes", "Not yet", 
"Don't know")), q417 = structure(1:4, .Names = c("Very useful", 
"Somewhat useful", "Not very useful", "Not at all useful"
)), ownership = structure(1:4, .Names = c("BUMN State-owned enterprise", 
"BUMD Regional-owned enterprise", "Foreign private ownership", 
"Domestic private ownership")), type = structure(c(10L, 20L, 
40L), .Names = c("Bank", "Pension Fund", "Financing Institution"
))), .Names = c("Q36", "q37", "q38", "q39", "q310", "q411", 
"q413", "q414", "q417", "ownership", "type")), .Names = c("risk", 
"cap", "FS_qual", "best_prac", "const_risk", "appr", "instr", 
"refin", "reg", "prop_qual"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to use the `likert()` function from the `likert library` to assemble diverging stacked bar charts and get the following error message:

```
lik <- likert(mybs)
Error in dimnames(x)[[2]] <- levels : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

I am not quite sure what this means. Can somebody point me towards resolving this error message?

Edit:

Okay, the problem seems to have been one of conflicting packages: I loaded the HH library and the likert library which seems to lead to the problem with library(likert).

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252       LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] HH_3.1-15           gridExtra_0.9.1     multcomp_1.4-0      TH.data_1.0-6       survival_2.38-1    
[6] mvtnorm_1.0-2       latticeExtra_0.6-26 RColorBrewer_1.1-2  lattice_0.20-31     likert_1.2         
[11] xtable_1.7-4        ggplot2_1.0.1       dplyr_0.4.1         plyr_1.8.1          foreign_0.8-63     
[16] lubridate_1.3.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] abind_1.4-3      acepack_1.3-3.3  assertthat_0.1   bitops_1.0-6     car_2.0-25       class_7.3-12    
[7] cluster_2.0.1    codetools_0.2-11 colorspace_1.2-6 DBI_0.3.1          digest_0.6.8     e1071_1.6-4     
[13] Formula_1.2-1    gtable_0.1.2     Hmisc_3.15-0     htmltools_0.2.6  httpuv_1.3.2     httr_0.6.1      
[19] lazyeval_0.1.10  leaps_2.9        lme4_1.1-7       magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-40      Matrix_1.2-0    
[25] memoise_0.2.1    mgcv_1.8-6       mime_0.3         minqa_1.2.4      mnormt_1.5-2     munsell_0.4.2   
[31] nlme_3.1-120     nloptr_1.0.4     nnet_7.3-9       parallel_3.1.3   pbkrtest_0.4-2   proto_0.3-10    
[37] psych_1.5.1      quantreg_5.11    R6_2.0.1         Rcmdr_2.1-7      RcmdrMisc_1.0-2  Rcpp_0.11.5     
[43] RCurl_1.95-4.5   reshape_0.8.5    reshape2_1.4.1   RJSONIO_1.3-0    rpart_4.1-9      sandwich_2.3-3  
[49] scales_0.2.4     shiny_0.11.1     SparseM_1.6      splines_3.1.3    stringr_0.6.2    swirl_2.2.21    
[55] tcltk_3.1.3      tcltk2_1.2-11    testthat_0.9.1   tools_3.1.3      vcd_1.3-2        yaml_2.1.13     
[61] zoo_1.7-12
```

So the problem seems to be with the `likert()` function in library(HH), not library(likert). Has someone experienced similar trouble?

Comment: Please see [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for better ways to include data in your question. If we can't copy/paste the code into R to get the same error as you, it's much harder to help you.

Comment: okay, I cannot see a way to reproduce the data in R without attaching the original data. However, I tried dput(head(x)) to at least give an overview, hope that is better.
there must be something wrong with the dimnames - I tried to give the data.frame appropriate dimnames(), but that did not seem to help..

Answer (score 1):

you must specify the function from the package you want to use:

```
likert::likert(Data)
HH::likert(Data)
```

;)